# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4366 pos 12: '<optimized out>': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter
I am getting this exception while navigating to another screen on button click.
Here is the code..

```
 trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.cancel,
                          size: 30.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ) ,
                        onPressed:() => Navigator.push(
                          context, 
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> 
                          CancelPage()
                      ),
```

Following is the code for CancelPage

```
class CancelPage extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          "Reason",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[600],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Form(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: new TextFormField(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed:()=> Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: new Text("Submit"),
                        color: Colors.red[900],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed:null,
                        child: new Text("Cancel"),
                        color: Colors.red[900],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
}
```

I am getting exception when I click on cancel iconbutton

package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart: Failed assertion: line 4366 pos 12: 'optimized out': is not true.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Please post the code and not the images

Comment: Posted the code. Please help.